# Slightly changed limit with e

Tags: limits

I know that
$$x_n \to 0 \implies (1+x_n)^{1 \over x_n} \to e$$
A special case
$$\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}\left(1 + {1 \over n}\right)^n = e$$

Now, I am trying to find
$$\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}\left(1 + {1 \over n(n+2)}\right)^n$$

What is the easiest way to approach this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If one knows that, by the Taylor series expansion, as $x \to 0$,
$$
\log(1+x)=x+o(x)
$$ one gets  that, as $n \to \infty$,
$$
\log\left( 1+\frac1{n(n+2)}\right)=\frac1{n(n+2)}+o\left(\frac1{n^2} \right)
$$ giving, as $n \to \infty$,
$$
\left(1 + {1 \over n(n+2)}\right)^n=e^{\large n\log\left( 1+\frac1{n(n+2)}\right)}=e^{\large \frac1{n+2}+o\left(\frac1{n} \right)} \to e^0=1.
$$

Answer (score 1):

$$1\le\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}\left(1 + {1 \over n(n+2)}\right)^n=\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}\left(1 + {1 \over n(n+2)}\right)^{n(n+2)\frac1{n+2}}\le\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}e^{\frac1{n+2}}=e^0=1$$

Comment: I think there is problem in your answer because why the $\frac{1}{n+2}$ remains after $n$ go to infinity

Comment: @E.H.E I admit it's not a rigorous answer, but may suffice the OP's wish to get an easy way to approach it..

Comment: But this approach sometimes  doesn't work.

Comment: @E.H.E I tried to change to $\le$ using that $(1+\frac1x)^x$ is an increasing function.

Answer (score 0):

Take the log:
$$\frac{\ln \left(1+\frac{1}{n(n+2)}\right)}{n}$$
$$=\frac{\ln \left(1+\frac{1}{n(n+2)}\right)}{\frac{1}{n(n+2)}}\frac{1}{n^2(n+2)}$$
We get a limit of $0$ so the original expression limits to $1$.